# QT in Visual Studio 2015 - Auto generated moc files contain #errors

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5.7

I have tried to open and compile an old project in visual studio 2015 (with QT 5.7.1). The project had been implemented  with visual studio 2008 and QT 4. I have do all necessary things (changed QT include paths, link *.dll versions etc). Thereafter clean all auto generated files and recompile the project. There were no any compiling errors, but it has linking errors (regarding moc files). I manually cleaned all moc files, ui_xxxx.h files and tried to build the project again. But this linking error problems were not resolved.

The linking error is below.

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * 

__thiscall <Class Name>::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@<Class Name>@rules@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)    <Project Name>  D:\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx\<Class Name>.obj   1
```

When I checking the auto generated moc file, it had below errors. Please note  that I have properly included 'QObject' in the header file.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <QtCore/qbytearray.h>
#include <QtCore/qmetatype.h>
#if !defined(Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION)
#error "The header file 'file_name.h' doesn't include <QObject>."
#elif Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION != 67
#error "This file was generated using the moc from 5.7.1. It"
#error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."
#error "(The moc has changed too much.)"
#endif
```

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: The `#error` directives of the header file will be reported much much earlier in the build process. Linking, where your actual error come from, is the last stage of building.

Comment: As for the error you get, you don't seem to properly define some class.

Comment: But I have checked, The corresponding class has been completely defined. And also 'QObject' has been included.

Any hint about the 'LNK2001 unresolved external symbol' issue?

Comment: Do you perhaps forget to run `moc` and other tools needed for the signal/slot mechanism of Qt to work? Do you remember to build with the auto-generated files?

Comment: I have set the header file build type as Custom Build Tool and set Custom Build Tool general properties correctly in the visual studio project. The "$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe" is contained in the command line property value of the General properties of the Custom Build Tool

Comment: And the generated source files? Are they added to the project and built with it?

Comment: I forgot to attach generated 'moc_*' files to the project file. I retry after attaching those generated fiels to the project, the KNK2001 issue was fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237526/discussion-between-ishara-madushan-and-some-programmer-dude).